# Spring boot api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hive, swagger

I am currently working on the development of a Spring Boot API designed to retrieve data from a Hive database based on specific queries related to the 'device_id' attribute within the data table. The goal is to format the retrieved data as a JSON response. Additionally, I am seeking guidance on the integration of Swagger API documentation.

While in the process of coding this solution, I have encountered multiple challenges and errors. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance from the community.

Comment: Please specify the problem properly, in which part you're getting errors? Try to find out and mention that.

Comment: Is there a specific error code you are getting trying to run the app?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems you need to solve to help you out:

1. Ensure you've setup Spring Boot to run without anything complicated. A simple hello world would ensure your IDE and basics are done
2. Setup a REST service, there are plenty of [tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-and-java-based-configuration)
3. Setup [Swagger](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)
4. Connect to hive with a JDBC, create a service for this for your controller to call when the REST service is called [tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/hive.html)

Make sure you've programmed each first and they are working before going on to the next step, otherwise debugging becomes a nightmare if you try to set these up all at the same time.